# Find all values that match a parameter in a nested ruby hash

Tags: ruby, select, hash

If I have a multi-nested hash like so

```
{
  "Monday"=>{
    "North"=>{
      "Group 1"=>[
        {:name=>"Event A", :type=>"Private"},
        {:name=>"Event B", :type=>"Public"},
      ]
    },
    "South"=>{
      "Group 1"=>[
        {:name=>"Event c", :type=>"Private"},
        {:name=>"Event D", :type=>"Public"},
        {:name=>"Event E", :type=>"Private"},
      ]
    }
  },
  "Tuesday"=>{
    "North"=>{
      "Group 1"=>[
        {:name=>"Event F", :type=>"Private"},
        {:name=>"Event G", :type=>"Public"},
      ]
    },
    "South"=>{
      "Group 1"=>[
        {:name=>"Event H", :type=>"Private"},
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to search within the hash for all Events that have a `type` that is equal to `Private`

How would I go about doing this without knowing exactly what the values of the keys will be in the hash?

Comment: There is no Ruby method for that. It is a good problem for you to solve by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If using the *gem* is an option, there is [`iteraptor`](https://github.com/am-kantox/iteraptor), that is explicitly about iterating deeply nested structures.

Assuming your original hash is named `hash`, here we go:

```
hash.iteraptor.
     each(full_parent: true, yield_all: true).
     with_object({}) do |(parent, (k, v)), acc|
  (acc[parent[0...-1]] ||= []) << k if
    parent.last.is_a?(Integer) && v.nil? && k.is_a?(Hash) && k[:type] == "Private"
end
```

Resulting in:

```
#⇒ {["Monday", "North", "Group 1"] =>
#       [{:name=>"Event A", :type=>"Private"}],
#   ["Monday", "South", "Group 1"] =>
#       [{:name=>"Event c", :type=>"Private"},
#        {:name=>"Event E", :type=>"Private"}],
#   ["Tuesday", "North", "Group 1"] =>
#       [{:name=>"Event F", :type=>"Private"}],
#   ["Tuesday", "South", "Group 1"] =>
#       [{:name=>"Event H", :type=>"Private"}]}
```

Comment: As soon as I saw the title I thought mudasobwa is going to share iteraptor :)

Comment: @engineersmnky right, it was written to avoid redoing these tasks :)

Answer (score 1):

In solving this recursively I have made three assumptions:

- There can be any number of nested arrays and hashes;
- `:type` is the only known key;
- if a hash contains the key `:type` it contains exactly one other key.

```
def get_em(obj)
  arr = []
  case obj
  when Hash
    obj.values.each do |v|
      case v
      when "Private"
        arr += obj.values-[v]
      when Hash, Array
        arr += get_em(v)
      end
    end
  when Array
    obj.each { |e| arr += get_em(e) if Hash === e || Array === e }
  end
  arr
end
```

If `h` is the hash given in the example,

```
get_em(h)
  #=> ["Event A", "Event C", "Event E", "Event F", "Event H"]
```

Note `Hash === e` is equivalent to `e.is_a?(Hash)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this recursion:

```
  def hash_match(the_hash)
    found=false
    the_hash.each do |key, value|
      if value.is_a?(Hash)
        if hash_match(value)
          if value.has_key :name
            puts value[:name]
          end
        end
      elsif value.is_a?(Array)
        value.each do |element|
          if element.is_a?(Hash)
            if hash_match(element)
              if element.has_key? :name
                puts element[:name]
              end
            end
          end
        end
      else
        if key==:type && value=="Private"
          found=true
        end
      end
    end
    return found
  end
```

Then just call `hash_match(your_hash)`